# A Thematic Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

*in history, it was assumed

i possessed only five

a change in tense, a compound word

you'll see me come alive

a skyward gun, but don't be scared

your judgement's preconceived

the best in life appears to those

when through these it's perceived*

The answer is a single word.
Please be nice, this is my first post on here.
If you solve it, please explain each line :)

Comment: HINT1: the 5th and 6th line can be solved by carefully considering wordplay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shamelessly swiped from Gareth.
Hazarding a guess in an attempt to complete this answer:

> ROSE. (Appropriately for Valentine's Day.)

*in history, it was assumed

i possessed only five*

> Wild roses only have five petals, and indeed the flowers of most rose species have just five.

*a change in tense, a compound word

you'll see me come alive*

> **rose** → **rise** (change in tense)  → **sunrise** (compound word):
>  the sun coming alive

*a skyward gun, ...*

> ... may reference the **pistil**, the female portion of flowers including the rose. Different species of roses have different numbers of pistils, with most having several. While its name sounds like a gun, a pistil is nothing to be afraid of.

*... but don't be scared*

> No need to run off!  Stay, you guys!  **Stamen**!  (Yesh, it's a stretch. Humor me.)

*your judgement's preconceived*

> *Judgement* may hint at **stigma**, and *preconceived* may reference the unfertilized **egg** in the **ovary** - all parts of the **pistil** which, together with the **stamen**, are the reproductive systems of the rose.

*the best in life appears to those

when through these it's perceived*

> Rose-colored glasses, of course.

If this is correct, [@Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79706) should also get an upvote for shoving us quite far in the right direction.

Comment: You are correct on the first part of the larger paragraph, but split it into two!

Comment: You have figured out the fifth line -- the sixth line is also of significance! I would suggest to keep thinking along the same train of thought that you did to figure out the former.

Comment: @visualnotsobasic Nothing at all comes to mind, I'm afraid - there's not enough there for me to grasp. (That happens sometimes. hehe)

Comment: You are genuinely so close. I'm certain you can get it. I'll try to think of another hint

Comment: You've nailed it. I've given Gareth an upvote as well and will be marking this as the answer! Edit: Except for the stamen part, nothing was intended there haha, but stigma is spot on! The ovaries is also quite clever - I had not thought of that

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps (though there are some gaps in my explanations below, so perhaps not) the single word is

> ROSE. (Appropriately for Valentine's Day.)

*in history, it was assumed

i possessed only five*

> A reference, perhaps, to the five-petalled symbols of the House of Lancaster and the House of York, who fought the "Wars of the Roses"

*a change in tense, a compound word

you'll see me come alive*

> If you have the misfortune to become a zombie, or the good fortune to be resurrected, you *rise* from the dead. (I'm not sure, though, where the "compound word" comes in.)

*a skyward gun, but don't be scared

your judgement's preconceived*

I don't have a good explanation for these lines.

*the best in life appears to those

when through these it's perceived*

> A reference to [rose-coloured spectacles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose-colored_glasses).

Comment: "skyward gun" may be a reference to rot13(Thaf A' Ebfrf)

Comment: This is close, perhaps think a little more on the second and third parts!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Power

in history, it was assumed

> People assumed power in history.

i possessed only five

> Power has 5 letters.

a change in tense, a compound word

> I am not sure about this clue, but powering has "ring" and "power" in it?

you'll see me come alive
a skyward gun, but don't be scared

> Military power

your judgement's preconceived
the best in life appears to those
when through these it's perceived

> Power can lead to a rich life.

Comment: Not the answer, but very clever and could fit!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> senses?

---

in history, it was assumed
i possessed only five

> (sight, touch, smell, sound, taste)

a change in tense, a compound word
you'll see me come alive

> (come to one's senses?)

a skyward gun, but don't be scared

> (not sure about this one)

your judgement's preconceived

> (our senses are intuitive / can't be controlled)

the best in life appears to those
when through these it's perceived

> (heart before head > feelings before logic etc) ??

Comment: This is actually a really cool answer! It's not the correct one, but it's well thought out.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have speculated, I believe the answer is

> Rose

*in history, it was assumed

i possessed only five*

This bit confuses me

> I would say this has to do with roses having five petals, except for the *rosa sericea*, but "I possessed *only* five" seems to imply that they have more, not less.

*a change in tense, a compound word

you'll see me come alive*

> As [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79707/57192) said, this is probably "sunrise". Plants photosynthesise, so they come alive in a sense. Although, roses don't close up at night.

Edit:
*a skyward gun, but don't be scared*

> Going off your comment, this relates to the pistil of the rose. Pretty on the nose

*your judgement's preconceived*

> Possible reference to the idiom "every rose has its thorns", meaning everyone has their good and bad elements. Is this meant to imply that we see the "pistil" as a threat because of a preconceived fear from the idiom? Or just simply that "pistil" sounds like "pistol" and we take that as the threat?

*the best in life appears to those

when through these it's perceived*

> As [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/79706/57192) said, this is a reference to rose-tinted glasses. I believe this ties in with telescopes as well.

Comment: You're spot on with three parts, however the third part with the gun is still off! It relates directly to the flower

Comment: Updated the skyward gun part there